# OpenShift Origin and Jenkins --> Permission denied

Tags: maven, jenkins, openshift, selinux

I get the following error with a Jenkins Pipeline Java / Maven job on OpenShift Origin:

```
[workspace] $ 
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn clean package
Error: dl failure on line 893
Error: failed /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk-
8/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so, because 
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk-8/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so: 
cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The strange thing is that it works well on my local MiniShift with the same and latest Jenkins template.

Anyone an idee? Someting to do with SELinux?