# How OpenShift determine the scc for the pod?

Tags: openshift

I am struggle with the scc's within OpenShift. All my pods are made with scc: restricted. But now I want some pods in privileged mode.

I tried with this command:

```
$ oc edit scc privileged
```

And add serviceaccount and namespace

Als tried to make a new scc with users:

```
$ oc create -f scc.yaml
```

But all new pods are still create with scc: restricted :-(

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `oc adm policy add-role-to-user -z default somerole`. The question is why you would want to do that. Running containers with root or other elevated privileges is usually a bad idea and unless you have cluster admin access for the OpenShift cluster, you cannot enable such privileges. The need to run with extra privileges is generally indicative of a poorly constructed image. Images should be designed to run as an arbitrary non root user.

Comment: I agree what you say, but I am using the Jenkins persistent template and I get errors when I using the maven command "not enough rights". The strange thing is when I use the same template on Minishift all is working. On OpenShift Origin it works only when I change the template code from "privileged false" to "privileged true". Is there a better way to get maven work within the Jenkins pod?

Comment: What Jenkins template are you talking about? Aren't you just selecting 'Jenkins (Persistent)' from the 'Continuous Integration & Deployment' category when using 'Add to project' from the web console of OpenShift Online?

Comment: Yes I am using Jenkins (Persistent) template. And in that template I changed the 'privileged false' to 'privileged true'. If I add this tempate to the project, the Jenkins pod is now 'privileged'. So I can run the maven commands. If there is another way to do that? Let me know. Also posted with the title "OpenShift Origin and Jenkins --> Permission denied".

Comment: The assumption would be that since that is available from 'Add to project', it should work out of the box and you should not need to be fiddling with the template yourself to override things. You certainly shouldn't need to set pods to ``privileged`` unless you are trying to do very strange things. What are you doing that needs privileged pods? Also, when you say works in OpenShift Origin, you know that Minishift is still OpenShift Origin. Can you clarify what cluster you are using, your own that you have set up?

Comment: Lets switch to my other question, because thats more specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810450/openshift-origin-and-jenkins-permission-denied. Here  you see the error with Maven. Today we have also some overcommiting errors (OOMKilled?)